# C# Regex - How to validate for either specific words or numbers but not both

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate a value and the requirement is it may either contain digits 0-9 or a specific words but not both.

I am using the following expression

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b(Private Bag)\b|[0-9]");
```

However, if find that using the above expression for validating is passing for all scenarios.

Where am I going wrong with this regex?

Comment: Why not use two regular expressions?  One that checks for value number strings, and the other checks for specific words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to put start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors around your pattern. Otherwise the pattern would match any value that contains your specific word or a digit, regardless of what else appears in the string. Also, it sounds like you need to include one or more (`+`) digits:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:(Private Bag)|[0-9]+)$");
```

This pattern will match a string that contains `Private Bag` or one or more decimal digits and nothing else.

Or if you don't care about the grouping, this is a bit simpler:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(Private Bag|[0-9]+)$");
```

Comment: For Validations the match groups don't matter, so you could remove the `?:`. Or add it to both groups to be consequent :)

Comment: @dognose Generally if someone posts a question that has groups I try to preserve those same groups in my answer. But in this case, you're right, that doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: Even though the groups are not necessary, I find the answer with groups to be more appealing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is your problem statement

> the requirement is it may either contain digits 0-9 or a specific words but not both.

(with the unspoken requirement that other stuff is valid), then you'll need to use *negative lookahead* (`(?!xxx)`) and *negative lookbehind* (`(?<!xxx`) assertions. For instance, this regular expression:

```
(?<!.*(foo|bar).*)(\d+)(?!.*(foo|bar).*)
```

should match

- 1 or more decimal digits (`(\d+)`),
- **not** preceded by either `foo` or `bar` anywhere prior the digits found, and
- **not** followed by either `foo` or `bar` anywhere after the digits found

Then you'll need its inverse:

```
(?<!.*(\d+).*)(foo|bar)(?!.*(\d+).*)
```

Add in a little grouping and alternation

```
((?<!.*(foo|bar).*)(\d+)(?!.*(foo|bar).*))|((?<!.*(\d+).*)(foo|bar)(?!.*(\d+).*))
```

And Bob's yer uncle. The above should match either

- a sequence of decimal digits that is neither preceded nor followed by `foo` or `bar`, or...
- an instance `foo` or `bar` that is neither preceded nor followed by a sequence of decimal digits.

Easy! Or something.

You should note, especially if the text being matched is long, that this is almost certainly not very efficient as it involves potentially a lot of backtracking and lookahead.